# SMS verification to avoid multi account

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm planning to create an app and I do not want multi-account, is SMS verification the best way? I've thought with email verification, but for me it does not make sense since I can create fake emails and then sign up with that one. That's why I ended up thinking SMS verification could do the "trick", I know to avoid multi-account is hard, but I can avoid it with SMS because phone number is uniq.

I've been reading [Firebase Phone-Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), but I'm seeing I only can verify 10k users per month (free), from now is ok, but when growing it will be a problem, is there any other api to use OTP?

### Edit

Is it safe to create my own service? Let's say this would be the flow.

User puts the phone number on Android phone
Android sends that phone number to server
Server uses an API to send SMS 
Server knows then the SMS is sent or not, so it will store the code
Android receives the SMS (without permissions in manifest) then is sent to backend to do the verification

Comment: what is "multi account"

Comment: If you're aiming to deploy to play store exclusively I don't think so. Firebase auth uses google services to validate incoming SMS messages and those are internally installed on all devices (that access the play store at least) and have elevated privileges. Any third party APIs would need to be embedded within your app and that would require SMS permission which disqualifies your app from being published.

Comment: Good to know this @Pawel, and create my own service? Like, from my app send the phone number via POST to my server, server uses an API to send SMS it sends it to that phone number, it stores the code in backend and then from the app I send the code that I see then server does the verification.

Comment: @Joe multi account means multiple account, 1 guy with more than one account.

Comment: It will work of course, firebase phone auth does pretty much that but it also automatically reads incoming sms code which you won't be able to reproduce.

Comment: How about dual USIM? There's plenty of devices which support that... and so the logic of this "security" concept is fundamentally flawed. And even if someone once showed a real ID to obtain the USIM, this is not always the ID of the actual user. The reality is, that one can buy USIM in the bulk and that there is no limit of one USIM per device or user.

Comment: About using third party services to send SMS: it will cost, based on the country of the receiver, so I guess Firebase Phone Auth is the most cost effective solution